# I can't open my lan world!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm trying to open my LAN world but I cant get the IP for my friend when I try!
It just gives me 5 numbers but when I tried it didn't work (note that we are on different WIFI and in different places).

Comment: When you connect to a network, you have many IP addresses, though they're really describing where you are inside the bigger, wider web. The IP address that Minecraft gives you is your local address; only usable by people within the same Wi-Fi network as you.

Answer (score 2):

A LAN (Local Area Network) world will only work if you're on the same WIFI, or network.

So what you need to do is install Hamachi, make a new network, and get your friend to join the network. Then your friend should copy your IPv4 address through Hamachi.

Next when you open to LAN, your friend goes into direct connect, adds your IPv4 address followed by : and the port (that 5 digit number it gave you).

There are many tutorials online, including [this one](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Hamachi_connection_LAN) from the wiki itself.